# Regex with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

It is necessary to make that in input it was possible to drive and with a format "AB 12" (the letter a letter a space number number). If the input does not match the format - just to replace the void.

Comment: I suggest using a website like [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) that allow you to create regex and see if/how they work.

Comment: I do not know how to implement such an input to immediately correct the values

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 gives you the pattern attribute, which allows you to require a certain pattern. In this case, you'd want pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]+"

It doesn't matter that older browser don't support this, because you should always validate on the server side.